# Call the overload method 'equals' for a generic type

Tags: java, oop, generics, equals

I'm trying to call the 'equals' method from a generic type.
On run time the type has an overload for 'equals'
but the Object.equals(Object obj)‬ is still triggered.

This is the generic class which calls 'equals'.

```java
public class SortedGroup <T> {
    void func(T element1,T element2) {
        if (element1.equals(element2))
            System.out.println("yes");
        else
            System.out.println("no");
}
```

This is the new type class that overloads 'equals'

```java
public class Person {
    private int ID;
    public Person(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
...
    public boolean equals(Person o) {
        return (this.ID == o.ID);
    }
...
}
```

and this is main.

```java
Person p1 = new Person(1);
Person p2 = new Person(1);
SortedGroup<Person> SG = new SortedGroup<Person>();

SG.func(p1,p2);
}
```

I expect the output be `yes` but the actual output `no`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not overriding `equals`, you are *overloading* it (same method name, different signature).  To override `equals` from `Object` correctly, you must match the method signature.  This means that your `equals` method must take an `Object`, not a `Person`.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {  // ...
```

It is good practice to include the `@Override` annotation on any method intended to override a method from a superclass or implement a method from an interface.  If you had done so, then the compiler would have alerted you to the fact that your method didn't override `equals`.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {  // ...
```

This also means that you'll need to test if the object passed in is actually a `Person` before casting and comparing member values.

It is also good practice to override `hashCode` so that is is consistent with `equals`, according to the [`hashCode` contract](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I know I'm not overriding.
But why my overload method doesn't work?
The program on "run-time" spouse to call ```equals``` that take a ```Person``` type.

Comment: @Tal It does not work because SortedGroup func compilation would resolve your call to equals to equals(Object) and not equals(Person) since it does not know that T is going to be Person in runtime. You must put yourself in the compiler position, it only can work with the information it is given in the file its compiling. If you bound ```T``` to be always a ```Person``` (```<T extends Person>```) then it will probably work. However you should not do this and instead properly overload ```equals(Objects)``` (and ```hashCode()```)...

Comment: ... since you would still have problems with other classes that relay on equals and hashCode like the containers in ```java.util.*``` (e.g. ```ArrayList```, ```HashMap```... ). @Tal